# Установка библиотек на python3.7 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pip

Не понимаю как скачивать библиотеки для питона 3.7, на ubuntu если я ввожу pip3 install python-dotenv, при запуске проекта питон 3.7 его не видит, хотя питон 3.9.6 видит его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python3.7 -m pip install python-dotenv
```